# Restricting any access to a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I realize a gem might be the best answer to my situation, but I really want to program it manually if possible. But I will still accept any suggestions for a gem to cover what I want. Anyway, on to the question...

I have a model Device and the normal model Users (devise gem) that has a join table devices_users. Device has a field "user_ids", which is an integer to represent the user ids of who has access (which is an array if I have multiple, but that's not really relevant to the question).

I want to restrict access to Device *entirely* if the user_ids field is not their user id. When I say entirely, I mean I have a lot of places they could theoretically access it:

1) I have multiple methods in my models that are called in views, and access Device data directly - such as:

```
if Device.all.where(:device_guid => model.device_id).first == nil
```

2) Views sometimes directly call upon Device, such as a collection select. It should not show up as a viable option.

3) They should have no controller access at all. No show, no index, nothing. (This seemed the easiest to implement, just a before_filter).

My big thing though - there has to be one simple way to restrict access entirely. Anything I did in the application controller only restricts controller access. Nothing I've tried seems to prevent access to the methods in the models (unless I individually restrict each one - and I have a lot of them), nor the views (again, unless I restrict each instance, which I have a lot of).

Is there a simple way to restrict it entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just qualify the initial lookup by the relevant user, like this:

`user.devices`

you can still do things like:

`user.devices.where(something: true)`

Comment: How exactly does user.devices work? Does the join table automatically cover that - so only devices joined through the join table apply to that search?  Or do I need to do something like:

`user.devices.where(device.user_ids.include(user.id))`

Comment: This happens automatically, and will basically work like your example code. You can watch the log and see the SQL generated, if you're curious.

Comment: This is working perfectly, thanks! I have a related question, but I'll make a separate one if I can't find an answer elsewhere.