# Restrict all access to a model based on information from another model (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I initially asked a similar question in [Restricting any access to a model in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394098/restricting-any-access-to-a-model-in-rails) - but this hasn't covered my complete needs.

I have a Dataapi model with many entries:

```
create_table "dataapis", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "device_id"
  t.datetime "start_time"
  t.datetime "end_time"
end
```

I have a Sandbox model with information on how I want to restrict the access (the Sandbox entries are defined in my admin panel).

```
create_table "sandboxes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "device_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "start_date"
  t.datetime "end_date"
end
```

Effectively, I only want users to have access to the dataapi if they have an appropriate entry in the Sandbox, which restricts access by:
 - User
 - Start DateTime
 - End DateTime
 - Access to the device that sent the dataapi (already handled that part in previous question).

I can't seem to find a way to do this though - models don't have access to @user, so I can't check that in the default scope.  Any recommendations? I've tried looking at gems (CanCanCan, Pundit, etc) but they only do controller-based authorization. I want this restriction to apply to *all* queries to dataapi, regardless of what controller called it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Declarative Authorization gem which provides authorization at the model level.

https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization

It gives you a query method that filters based on user's permissions...

```
Employee.with_permissions_to(:read).find(:all, :conditions => ...)
```

Another alternative is you can store the current_user in the Dataapi model and populate it with an around_filter.

In the model...

```
class Dataapi < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user]
  end

  def self.current_user=(some_user)
    Thread.current[:current_user] = some_user
  end
end
```

In the application controller...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :store_current_user

  def store_current_user
    Dataapi.current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    yield
  ensure
    Dataapi.current_user = nil
  end             
end
```

You can then reference the current_user in the Dataapi model using `Dataapi.current_user`

Comment: I'll look into Delcarative Authorization, didn't know about that one.
Admins sometimes pose as other users to view data as they do, so it needs to be based off of our custom variable posed_user instead of current user. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Using `declarative_authorization`?  Just change the before_filter that sets who the current user is.  They suggest...
  `before_filter { |c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user }`
... but you can do ...   `before_filter { |c| Authorization.current_user = c.posed_user }`

Comment: I'll give it a shot and select it as correct answer if this works, thanks!